# (0 , _react.useEffect) is not a function with Storybook in Docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use docker with docker-compose to developing my website. It has a container that use Storybook for manage component inside. When I look at "Form" Topic, it said :

```
TypeError: (0 , _react.useEffect) is not a function
    at LabelMapperComonent (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:68174:24)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:42312:15)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:42716:16)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:45552:16)
    at workLoop (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:45581:26)
    at renderRoot (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:45612:9)
    at performWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:46187:24)
    at performWork (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:46108:9)
    at performSyncWork (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:46085:5)
    at requestWork (http://localhost:7006/static/preview.bundle.js:45985:7)
```

I observe to find what is the reason and I found the error is this part :

```js
const LabelMapperComonent = ({ addField, name, label }) => {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      addField({ [name]: label })
    },
    [name, label]
  )

  return null
}
```

And I think this also cause the problem, too.

```
export const LabelMapper = connect(null, bindActionCreators.bind(null, { addField }))(LabelMapperComonent)
```

What am I go wrong , any way to fix?
Thank you for advice.